# How does imread scale 12bit images?

Tags: matlab, imread

I have a 12-bit pgm-image, which I read with imread. The result is a 16-bit image having values in the full range 0 to 2^16 - 1.

How does Matlab scale? Will

```
 X = imread('filename');
 X = uint16(double(X)*((2^12-1)/(2^16-1)));
```

recover the original intensities?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MATLAB does load PGM 12-bit images correctly. However, after MATLAB loads the images, the image values are rescaled from 12-bit to 16-bit.

MATLAB uses the following algorithm to scale the values from 12-bit to 16-bit:

```
% W contains the the 12-bit data loaded from file. Data is stored in 16-bit unsigned integer
% First 4 bits are 0. Consider 12-bit pixel color value of ABC
% Then W = 0ABC
X = bitshift(W,4); % X = ABC0
Y = bitshift(W,-8); %Y = 000A
Z = bitor(X,Y); %Z = ABCA 
% Z is the variable that is returned by IMREAD.
```

Workaround for this is like that

```
function out_image = imreadPGM12(filename)
out_image = imread(filename);
out_image = floor(out_image./16);
return
```

Alternatively perform a 4 bit shift to the right:

```
function out_image = imreadPGM12(filename)
out_image = imread(filename);
out_image = bitshift(out_image,-4);
return
```

Further information can be found here:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/93578-why-are-12-bit-pgm-images-scaled-up-to-16-bit-value-representation-in-image-processing-toolbox-7-10

Comment: Link-only answers should contain at least relevant information so that if the link is broken then the answer is still valid. Can you wrap up what the link says? Thanks

Comment: @sof_dff Looks good, but I tried this `A = uint16(1:(2^12-1));
imwrite(A,'test.pgm','MaxValue',max(A(:)));
B = imread('test.pgm');`, and neither of your solutions would recover `A`. What did I misunderstand?

Comment: @jolo I'm a little bit confused by your example. In your example, if you remove max(A(:)) from imwrite you'll read what your wite.

Still I do not understand in what way your example relates to your initial question. Could you please explain?

Comment: @sof_dff I tried to create an example as in my question, i.e. an 12-bit .pgm-file. As you point out correctly removing `max(A(:))` will make `imread` read the correct values - which it shouldn't as you pointed out in your answer. The reason is that `imwrite` also uses some scaling (as can be seen by using `imfinfo` on the saved image) which I tried to work around by passing the `maxValue` argument.

Comment: @sof_dff I understood now how `imwrite` works and how I misused the `maxValue` argument.