# Why does MATLABs "imwrite" scale 12-bit images and how to circumvent this?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, png

I have an image given as an `N x M` - matrix with 12-bit data and I want to use `imwrite` to save the image as a `.pgm` file.

Why does MATLAB scale the image to 16bit? How can I circumvent this?

Using the `'MaxValue'` argument also seems to alter the image, as it can't be displayed properly afterwards e.g. in IrfanView.

Comment: I already wrote my answer but how is this question different from this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27186874/how-does-imread-scale-12bit-images ?

Comment: This is about `imwrite`, not `imread`.

Comment: `imwrite` only supports the writing of 8-bit, 16-bit or 32-bit images, which is why it probably scales to 16-bit.  I don't see a problem with taking your 12-bit intensities and scaling them to 16-bit.  What would happen is that one intensity that is 12-bit would be scaled to its equivalent intensity to 16-bit... so visually speaking, they should look the same.  The actual intensities themselves will obviously be different.  If you provide more context into why you need to preserve 12-bit, this may motivate me to write an answer for you.

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks. I read the 12-bit image into matlab to do some manipulation. After that I pass the manipulated images to another (non-matlab) program using the `system`-command, which needs the 12-bit values to be preserved, as it behaves differently otherwise.

Comment: @jolo - What is the image standard you are using? JPEG? TIFF? PPM? Depending on which standard you're using, there may be options available to you in order to get what you want.  `MaxValue` is an attribute only available to PPM and PGM images.

Comment: @rayryeng I am using PGM at the moment. If there is no solution sticking to PGM I could try changing to another format for which this would be possible.

Comment: @jolo - With PGM, then you should be able to set the `MaxValue` to `2^12 - 1`.  This didn't work?

Comment: @rayryeng No, but I'm not sure why. I tried to just read an image into matlab, undo the scaling done by `imread`, save it with `imwrite` using `MaxValue`. But afterwards, the image won't display properly in e.g. Irfanview, and my program also yields a different result.

Comment: You scaled each pixel by `(2^12 - 1) / (2^16 - 1)`, yes?  Also, did you make sure you casted your image to double, scaled, then cast back to `uint16`?

Comment: @rayryeng Yes, exactly. I also tried to create an example like `A=repmat(uint16(0:4000),1000,1); imwrite(A,'test.pgm','MaxValue',2^12-1);`, which is also not display correctly in Irfanview.

Comment: If all else fails, you can write your own PGM output function.  PGM format is super simple.  Build the file in an array of 8-bit unsigned integers and then call`fwrite(fileID,A)`. http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pgm.html

Comment: @japreiss  It is super simple to write a PGM, but to get it labeled as 12-bit data, you need the header written out to say so (e.g. `fprintf(fid, 'P5 %d %d %d\n', width, height, 2^12-1);`).  The format is nicely described in the link you have.  Thanks!

Comment: @japreiss +1 from me, too, definitely good knowledge for me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `MaxValue` parameter is a little counter intuitive.  It does specify to write the PGM tagged with a max value of a certain depth (e.g. 12-bit here), but it also tells `iwwrite` to rescale the data.  The rescaling happens in `writepnm>remap_pixel_values`:

```
function newdata = remap_pixel_values(data, maxval)
%REMAP_PIXEL_VALUES Remap pixel values in array of pixel values.
%
%   NEWDATA = REMAP_PIXEL_VALUES(DATA, MAXVAL) remaps the pixel values in
%   DATA as follows
%
%   Class of DATA   Input                    Output
%   -------------   -----                    ------
%   uint8           The set {0,1,...,255}    The set {0,1,...,maxval}
%   uint16          The set {0,1,...,65535}  The set {0,1,...,maxval}
%   double          The interval [0,1]       The set {0,1,...,maxval}
```

So with `uint16` data, it will rescale the data by applying a scale of `65535/maxval` via the bit shift `bitshift(data,-4);`.  You don't want it to rescale the data, but you also want it to write the file as 12-bit (this happens in `writepnm>write_raw_data`.  The workaround is to apply the opposite scale before calling `imwrite`:

```
Iscaled = uint16(double(I)*(2^16-1)/(2^12-1))
imwrite(Iscaled,'test.pgm','MaxValue',2^12-1)
```

Note that you could use double values scaled between [0,1] too, according to the table in the above code comments.

For *reading* 12-bit PGM/PPM, see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/93578-why-are-12-bit-pgm-images-scaled-up-to-16-bit-value-representation-in-image-processing-toolbox-7-10).

Comment: Huh!... go figure... you have to do the *opposite*.  BTW +1.

Comment: Great, thanks! That's certainly a surprising answer, at least to me!